# Apple Mach-O Linker Error during profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, linker-errors

So I ran into this wierd issue where I am able to compile and run my iOS project in simulator with out any issues but when I ran it for profiling with instrument (cmd + I) I am getting Apple mach o linker error for one of the library. I tried it reading to project but it did not helped. I also checked my search paths which looks as following

```
Other Linker Flags: -ObjC -all_load
Always Search User Paths: No
Framework Search Paths:$(SRCROOT) recursive
Library Search Paths:$(SRCROOT) recursive
```

I am getting following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TestFlight", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I missing anything in my linking phase which causing this thing to happen ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not finding the TestFlight library.  Easiest way to fix that is to find libTestFlight.a in the Xcode project browser and make sure your app is checked under "Target Membership" on the far right pane.